# IOException: Host is down in bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, ioexception

I have two android phone in Android4.1  May be I can call them phone A and phone B.
Then I know the MAC address and uuid of phone A. So what I want to do is that,I plan to give the MAC address and uuid of phone A to phone B,and make B connect to A in bluetooth.So A is the bluetooth server,B is bluetooth client.
But when I do it .The phone B said
     W/System.err(18404): java.io.IOException: Host is down

The code in phone A as server like that:

```
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {

        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {               
           Method m =  mBluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", new Class[] {int.class});
           tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket)m.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, new Object[]{25});
        Log.i("liyufei","in server  we begin at uuid = "+selfUuid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        Log.i("liyufei","listening is begin");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Log.i("liyufei","wait...............");
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            Log.i("liyufei","keep going socket is try to create");
            if (socket != null) {
                Log.i("liyufei","server socket accept!!!");
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_ACCEPT).sendToTarget();
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            Log.i("liyufei","socket is null");
        }
        Log.i("liyufei","while is stop");
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
            Log.i("liyufei","we try to Close server!!");
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code in phone B as client like that:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        Log.i("liyufei","new connect thread......");
        try {
            Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice,Integer.valueOf(25));
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();  
        try {
            Log.i("liyufei","we try to connect.....");
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (Exception connectException) {
            Log.i("liyufei","connect to server failed...");
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        Log.i("liyufei","client has success connect!!!");
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_CONNECT).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Then I just can get IOException:Host is down after mmSocket.connect(); in phone B
Who can help me???Thank you very much !!!!!
The Log after test suggestion from  @Waqas

```
09-25 14:31:26.587: I/liyufei(12453): new connect thread......
09-25 14:31:26.587: I/liyufei(12453): we begin in connect uuid = 66d77030-9982-42cf-88a7-272954408361
09-25 14:31:26.595: E/BluetoothService.cpp(308): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
09-25 14:31:26.595: I/liyufei(12453): we try to connect.....
09-25 14:31:26.900: D/PhoneStatusBar(389): disable: < expand* icons alerts ticker system_info back home recent clock >
09-25 14:31:26.970: D/dalvikvm(520): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 140K, 44% free 14337K/25415K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
09-25 14:31:26.986: I/dalvikvm-heap(520): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.297MB for 3409936-byte allocation
09-25 14:31:27.017: D/dalvikvm(520): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 31% free 17667K/25415K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 32ms
09-25 14:31:27.017: D/dalvikvm(520): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
09-25 14:31:31.720: I/liyufei(12453): connect to server failed...1
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453): java.io.IOException: Host is down
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:216)
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at com.example.android.beam.BeamBlueTooth$ConnectThread.run(BeamBlueTooth.java:297)
09-25 14:31:31.720: I/liyufei(12453): we try to connect.....
09-25 14:31:31.720: I/liyufei(12453): connect to server failed...2
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453): java.io.IOException: File descriptor in bad state
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:216)
09-25 14:31:31.720: W/System.err(12453):    at com.example.android.beam.BeamBlueTooth$ConnectThread.run(BeamBlueTooth.java:297)
09-25 14:31:31.720: I/liyufei(12453): we try to connect.....
09-25 14:31:31.728: I/liyufei(12453): connect to server failed...3
09-25 14:31:31.728: W/System.err(12453): java.io.IOException: File descriptor in bad state
09-25 14:31:31.728: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
09-25 14:31:31.728: W/System.err(12453):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:216)
09-25 14:31:31.728: W/System.err(12453):    at com.example.android.beam.BeamBlueTooth$ConnectThread.run(BeamBlueTooth.java:297)
```

Comment: can you try making the second attempt quickly (after failing first attempt)? or try to connect a couple of times quickly.

Comment: @Waqas  Do you mean I can connect phone A after I try it many times?why?  I will test your suggestion tomorrow,and tell you the answer!Thank you very much!

Comment: I've noticed this strange behavior with many of my phones (including Galaxy Nexus) in order to create socket connection with each other . Even the BluetoothChat demo app also doesn't work perfectly out of the box. Give a try to my suggestion and see if it works :)

Comment: @Waqas No,it doesn't work.I have added the Log.Do you think the two devices via Bluetooth connection must go through a process of mutual discovery?  As you know, I want to skip the process of mutual discovery, and make a direct connection.Can this program win out?

Comment: you should create a `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` connection to avoid discovery and pairing

Comment: @Waqas I change the code like this in server: Method m =  mBluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingInsecureRfcommOn", new Class[] {int.class});

Comment: And  in client like this Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}); But it still have the IOException as the log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17100/discussion-between-fly84021210-and-waqas)

Comment: @Waqas hi?Are you still there?

Comment: if you set your API level to 10 (Android 2.3.3) then you don't need to get it done via reflections. You may simply call the method names directly. Read more about [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) and it will help you for sure.

Comment: @Waqas May be I must use android 4.1 ,because I need Android Beam to transfer MAC address from Galaxy Nexus to Nexus s......So you can know my purpose.I want two phones can get bluetooth connection via NFC  :P

Comment: @fly84021210 Are you able to do it ? I am also facing the same problem.